# QGIS Default Metadata

Tags: qgis, metadata

In QGIS 3.6.2 (on Windows 10), one can open the properties of a layer, click on Metadata, and enter information about the layer. At the bottom of the properties window is the option to save metadata as a file (a QMD file) or "Save as Default".

Where are default metadata stored for PostGIS layers in @qgis 3.x? It's not in the project file because I didn't save a project file but when reloading layers from PostGIS, the metadata changes are preserved.

Comment: "Save as default" sounds to me like it's saved in your QGIS user profile, with other default QGIS settings like attribute table behavior. That's just a guess; you can test it by opening the layer in QGIS on another computer. If I'm right, the metadata will be missing. Other possibilities are that it's saved in the database, or as a sidecar file alongside the database.

Answer (score 2):

The development plan for metadata says it should be saved in a database table, but I don't know if it was implemented.  For file type sources it saves in a qmd file with the same name as the source, in the directory with it.

Answer (score 0):

I expected it to be saved into *public.qgis_layer_metadata*.
But from my experience it is saved in the same schema as the layer, in the "qgis_layer_metadata" table.